# How to get parameters from path in Bottle?

Tags: python, rest, parameters, path, bottle

When i execute this url:

```
http://domain:8081/forum?id=2&page=26
```

with this code:

```
@route('/forum')
def display_forum():
   forum_id = request.query.id
   page = request.query.page or '1'
   return template('Forum ID: {{id}} (page {{page}})', id=forum_id, page=page)
```

This return on webpage `Forum ID: 2 (page 26)`

I need to obtain the same result calling a dynamic rest url.
The url can be `http://domain:8081/forum/2/26` or `http://domain:8081/forum/city/place/day/hour`.
Don't exist a fixed number of parameters.
I saw some ideas in bottle documentation, perhaps something like wildcard filter `:path`.

Comment: What are you doing with 2nd url `http://domain:8081/forum/city/place/day/hour`?

Answer (score 3):

It won't scale to infinite routes, but something like this would work.

```
@route('/forum/<first>')
def test(first):
    return first

@route('/forum/<first>/<second>')
def test(first, second):
    return first, second

@route('/forum/<first>/<second>/<third>')
def test(first, second, third):
    return first, second, third

@route('/forum/<first>/<second>/<third>/<fourth>')
def test(first, second, third, fourth):
    return first, second, third, fourth
```

Comment: Not exactly what he is asking for. Here he is asking for GET parameters on the same endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Use Parameters

```
@route ('/forum/forum_id=:forum_id&page=:page')
def display_forum(forum_id,page):
   forum_id = request.query.id
   page = request.query.page or '1'
   return template('Forum ID: {{id}} (page {{page}})', id=forum_id, page=page)
```

Comment: @ron.rothman i just added parameters with his code if the above code will work then this will also work since i already tested  with parameters

Comment: I think you're confusing query parameters (after the `?`) with Bottle's dynamic path parameters.  You just converted the OP's query params to pattern-matched parts of the route, which is (a) odd, and (b) not what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `:path` wildcard filter as you have hinted.
In your example, you provided query parameters with key=value pairs and asked how to do the same using url paths but only using values with no limit of a fixed number of parameters.

`/forum?id=2&page=26`
`/forum/2/6`

Since we don't want a limit to the number of parameters, I feel that it makes sense to provide the keys in the url paths as pairs.

`/forum/id/2/page/26/city/chicago/place/opera/day/monday/hour/2:20pm`

Then I would parse it accordingly:

```py
from bottle import route, run, request, template
import re

@route("/forum/<url_paths:path>", method=["GET", "POST"])
def display_forum(url_paths=None):
    # -- parse the paths as pairs of /key/value/key/value...
    match = re.compile(r"/", re.VERBOSE)
    items = map(str, match.split(url_paths))
    url_params = dict(zip(items, items))

    # -- check for any GET or POST parameters and save as dict(),
    req_params = {k:v for (k,v) in request.params.items()}

    # -- merge the url_params with req_params into one dictionary object
    params = url_params | req_params

    # -- parse forum_id and page
    if params:
        forum_id = params.pop("id") if params.get("id") else "NA"
        page = params.pop("page") if params.get("page") else "1"
        tpl = """
        Forum ID: {{id}} (page {{page}})
        % for (key, value) in params.items():
            {{key}}: {{value}}
        %end

        """
        return template(tpl, id=forum_id, page=page, params=params)
    return "please provide url paths, query params, or post data"

run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8081, reloader=True)
```

### Sample Requests

**only url paths**

```sh
❯ curl "http://127.0.0.1:8081/forum/city/Miami/place/Dog%20Park/day/Wednesday/hour/8:20pm/id/8/page/7"

        Forum ID: 8 (page 7)
            city: Miami
            place: Dog Park
            day: Wednesday
            hour: 8:20pm
```

**url paths and query params**

```sh
❯ curl "http://127.0.0.1:8081/forum/city/Chicago/place/Opera%20House/day/Saturday/hour/6:20pm?id=2&page=26"

        Forum ID: 2 (page 26)
            city: Chicago
            place: Opera House
            day: Saturday
            hour: 6:20pm
```

**url paths and POST params**

```sh
❯ curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8081/forum/event/Yoga/city/Philadelphia/place/Gym/day/Tuesday/hour/8:00am" -d "id=2&page=3"

        Forum ID: 2 (page 3)
            event: Yoga
            city: Philadelphia
            place: Gym
            day: Tuesday
            hour: 8:00am
```

**url paths and POST form fields**

```sh
❯ curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8081/forum/event/Concert/city/Virginia%20Beach/place/GTE%20Amphitheatre/day/Friday/hour/7:20pm/price/\$65.00" -F "id=3" -F "page=16"

        Forum ID: 3 (page 16)
            event: Concert
            city: Virginia Beach
            place: GTE Amphitheatre
            day: Friday
            hour: 7:20pm
            price: $65.00
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to combine the form values with the query values making a unified API.

```
def merge_dicts(*args):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in args:
        result.update(dictionary)
    return result

payload = merge_dicts(dict(request.forms), dict(request.query.decode()))
id = payload['id']
page = payload['page']
```